# MERN Stack application same data appearing in other users dashboard

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mern

I attempted to get help on this twice but have not received the proper help to resolve the problem I am having. I am attempting one last time. I started learning MERN stack and completed a small project. However, the issue I am having is that when a user adds items, those same items appear on another user's dashboard. How can I code it so that the logged-in user only can see his/her data? I am learning a lot about this stack so I would appreciate it if I can get help regarding this issue. Thank you.

****models file Item.js file****

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Scheme

const ItemSchema = new Schema({

  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date:{
    type:Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  userId:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
```

}

```
});


module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);

****api folder item.js code****
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');



//Item model`enter code here`
const Item = require('../../models/Item');

// @route GET api/items
// @description Get All Items
// Access Public
router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
  Item.find({userId: req.body.userId})
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(items => res.json(items));

});

// @route POST api/items
// @description Create an item
// Access Private
router.post('/', auth, (req, res) =>{


  const newItem = new Item({
    name: req.body.name,
    userId: req.body.name


  });


  newItem.save().then(item => res.json(item));

});

// @route DELETE api/items/:id
// @description Delete an item
// Access Private
router.delete('/:id', auth, (req, res) =>{
  Item.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(item => item.remove().then(() => res.json({success:true})))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({success: false}));
});




module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Your item is in no way connected to a user. And you're retrieving _all_ items for every user. That's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have edited the code in my post and you can see that even with that I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: Can you add the code for the frontend that fetches all items. Also, you can remove all other code except for the model definition and the item route definitions.

Comment: I already have it on there called ItemModal.js

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what "fetching all items" means.

Comment: Just added the itemsActions.js on top. I believe that is what you are talking about

Comment: No, I meant the code that renders the items. The items that you said are appearing in every user.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at your schemas, you have no user identifier in the item schema to match which user has added that item, how are you finding out which item was added by which user?

Looking at your route for getting the items, you are making a query that gets all the items regardless of the user id.

The query should be built in a way

Pseudocode Example:

```
Item.find({where userId is currentUser.id})
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(items => res.json(items));
```

Comment: Danyal - I have edited the code in my post and you can see that even with what you suggested, I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: For userId, you are giving it `userId: req.body.name` which is the item name. Also, your schema type for it is ObjectId but you are giving it a `string` value judging by the `req.body.name`

Comment: You need to query the database directly to see if it's even storing these fields correctly or not, because looking at the code, it seems like you're still not creating a relation between the Item and the User, since you are passing it a string.